# What Accept-CH values are equivilent to User-Agent for identifying a browser?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, http-headers, user-agent, client-hints

Chrome plans on deprecating and freezing its *User-Agent* header June, 2020. The *User-Agent* is useful when debugging certain errors from logs because many browsers have different quirks depending on the version. *User-Agent* is being deprecated in favor for *Accept-CH* and *Sec-CH-UA-**.

What values do I need to put in *Accept-CH* in order for the browser to respond with the following user-agent information? What are the accompanying *Sec-CH-UA-** headers?

- Browser name and version.
- OS name and version.
- Architecture (32/64 bit x86, ARM, etc).
- Is mobile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this [page](https://wicg.github.io/ua-client-hints).

- **Browsername and version**
  `Sec-CH-UA-Model` and/or `Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version`
- **OS Name**
  `Sec-CH-UA-Platform` and/or `Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version`
- **Architecture**
  `Sec-CH-UA-Arch`
- **Is Mobile**
  `Sec-CH-UA-Mobile`

But keep in mind that the client hints are experimental.

#### Edit

To answer your question what you have to send to get the values from above:
Just remove the `SEC-CH-UA-`-prefix, so your header looks like this

```
Accept-CH: UA, Full-Version, Platform, Platform-Version, Arch, Mobile
```

Comment: on firefox and safari can use Accept-CH?

Comment: I'm not sure how to activate the client-hints in Firefox and safari. In Chrome you must activate them first. On this page you can test the client-hints: https://browserleaks.com/client-hints

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-CH